# Merging of 3 Hashtable into 1 based on common values they contain

Tags: java, vector

I have 3 vector as given below.Here Vector1, Vector2, Vector3 will not be of same size.below given is an ideal situation that will occur some time only.It might be possible that vector2 only contain one extra {} with d=3,... and vector1 and Vector3 will don't have that(d=3) entry.

```
Vector1 := [{a=Prity, b=Joshi, c=Pyarelal, d=1},{a=tiny, b=darji, c=Mohandas, d=2}]  
Vector2 := [{e=age-29, f=height-5, d=1},{e=age-52, f=height-6, d=2}]        
Vector3 := [{g=pet-dog, d=1},{g=pet-cat, d=2}]
```

I want a vector that will merge values and give me final vector as displayed below

```
Vector4 := [{a=Prity, b=Joshi, c=Pyarelal, d=1,e=age-29, f=height-5, g=pet-dog}, {a=tiny, b=darji, c=Mohandas, d=2, e=age-52, f=height-6, g=pet-cat}]
```

I implemented one logic but it is time consuming.Does anyone has better option ?????

```
int columnSize = Vector1.size() > Vector2.size() ? Vector1.size()
        : Vector2.size();
Hashtable finalHash[] = new Hashtable[columnSize];
for (i = 0; i < Vector1.size(); i++) {
    finalHash[i] = (Hashtable) Vector1.elementAt(i);
    for (int z = 0; z < Vector2.size(); z++) {
        Hashtable hashtwo = (Hashtable) Vector2.elementAt(z);
        if (hashtwo.containsValue(finalHash[i]
                .get("TQM_QUOTE_INCEPTION_DATE"))) {
            finalHash[i].putAll(hashtwo);
            Vector2.removeElementAt(z);
        }
    }
    for (int z = 0; z < Vector3.size(); z++) {
        Hashtable hashduerenew = (Hashtable) Vector3.elementAt(z);
        if (hashduerenew.containsValue(finalHash[i]
                .get("TQM_QUOTE_INCEPTION_DATE"))) {
            finalHash[i].putAll(hashduerenew);
            Vector3.removeElementAt(z);
        }
    }
}
columnSize = Vector2.size() > Vector3.size() ? Vector2.size() : Vector3
        .size();
Hashtable finalHashtable = new Hashtable();
for (int t = 0; t < Vector2.size(); t++, i++) {
    finalHashtable = (Hashtable) Vector2.elementAt(t);
    for (int z = 0; z < Vector3.size(); z++) {
        Hashtable hashtwo = (Hashtable) Vector3.elementAt(z);
        if (hashtwo.containsValue(finalHashtable
                .get("TQM_QUOTE_INCEPTION_DATE"))) {
            finalHash[i].putAll(hashtwo);
            Vector3.removeElementAt(z);
            break;
        }
    }
    finalHash[i].putAll(finalHashtable);
    Vector2.removeElementAt(t);
}
int t = 0;
while (t < Vector3.size()) {
    finalHash[i] = (Hashtable) Vector3.elementAt(t);
    t++;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Why not using data structure from the JDK ? ``List``s and ``Map``s ?

Comment: It is already developed(So m getting hastable'svector only :( ) and I have to merge it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think he wanted something like this:

```
private static Vector<Hashtable<Character, String>> vector1;
private static Vector<Hashtable<Character, String>> vector2;
private static Vector<Hashtable<Character, String>> vector3;

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    setUp();

    // Your final vector
    Vector<Hashtable<Character, String>> mergedVector = new Vector<Hashtable<Character, String>>();

    // Considering every vector has the same size
    addToMerged(mergedVector, vector1);
    addToMerged(mergedVector, vector2);
    addToMerged(mergedVector, vector3);

    // Print the result
    for (Hashtable<Character, String> hash : mergedVector) {
        for (Entry<Character, String> set : hash.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("KEY: " + set.getKey() + ", VALUE: "
                + set.getValue());
        }

        System.out.println("\nNext hashtable.\n");
    }
}

private static void setUp() {
    vector1 = new Vector<Hashtable<Character, String>>();
    Hashtable<Character, String> hash11 = new Hashtable<Character, String>();
    hash11.put('a', "Prity");
    hash11.put('b', "Joshi");
    hash11.put('c', "Pyarelal");
    hash11.put('d', "1");
    vector1.add(hash11);

    Hashtable<Character, String> hash12 = new Hashtable<Character, String>();
    hash12.put('a', "tiny");
    hash12.put('b', "darji");
    hash12.put('c', "Mohandas");
    hash12.put('d', "2");
    vector1.add(hash12);

    vector2 = new Vector<Hashtable<Character, String>>();
    Hashtable<Character, String> hash21 = new Hashtable<Character, String>();
    hash21.put('e', "age-29");
    hash21.put('f', "height-5");
    hash21.put('d', "1");
    vector2.add(hash21);

    Hashtable<Character, String> hash22 = new Hashtable<Character, String>();
    hash22.put('e', "age-52");
    hash22.put('f', "height-6");
    hash22.put('d', "2");
    vector2.add(hash22);

    vector3 = new Vector<Hashtable<Character, String>>();
    Hashtable<Character, String> hash31 = new Hashtable<Character, String>();
    hash31.put('g', "pet-dog");
    hash31.put('d', "1");
    vector3.add(hash31);

    Hashtable<Character, String> hash32 = new Hashtable<Character, String>();
    hash32.put('g', "pet-cat");
    hash32.put('d', "2");
    vector3.add(hash32);
}

private static void addToMerged(
    final Vector<Hashtable<Character, String>> mergedVector,
    final Vector<Hashtable<Character, String>> vector) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) {
        Hashtable<Character, String> hashtable = vector.get(i);
        for (Entry<Character, String> entrySet : hashtable.entrySet()) {
    boolean added = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < mergedVector.size() && !added; j++) {
        Hashtable<Character, String> hashtable2 = mergedVector
            .get(j);
        if (!hashtable2.containsKey(entrySet.getKey())) {
            hashtable2.put(entrySet.getKey(), entrySet.getValue());
            added = true;
            break;
        } else if (hashtable2.get(entrySet.getKey()).equals(
            entrySet.getValue())) {
            added = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!added) {
        Hashtable<Character, String> hashtable2 = new Hashtable<>();
        hashtable2.put(entrySet.getKey(), entrySet.getValue());
            mergedVector.add(hashtable2);
    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this code in different manner and if will have any doubt will come back with that doubt :) coz I represented here only sample data the vector contains string=string (not character=string)

Answer (score 0):

`Hashtable` doesn't keep the order in which you add the elements, so your vectors originally aren't going to look as you wrote them in your post, if you want to archieve that you will have to use `LinkedHashTable`.

Taking into account the comment before, you can merge your vectors like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vector<Hashtable<Character, String>> vector1 = new Vector<Hashtable<Character, String>>();
    Hashtable<Character, String> hash11 = new Hashtable<Character, String>();
    hash11.put('a', "Prity");
    hash11.put('b', "Joshi");
    hash11.put('c', "Pyarelal");
    hash11.put('d', "1");
    vector1.add(hash11);

    Hashtable<Character, String> hash12 = new Hashtable<Character, String>();
    hash12.put('a', "tiny");
    hash12.put('b', "darji");
    hash12.put('c', "Mohandas");
    hash12.put('d', "2");
    vector1.add(hash12);

    Vector<Hashtable<Character, String>> vector2 = new Vector<Hashtable<Character, String>>();
    Hashtable<Character, String> hash21 = new Hashtable<Character, String>();
    hash21.put('e', "age-29");
    hash21.put('f', "height-5");
    hash21.put('d', "1");
    vector2.add(hash21);

    Hashtable<Character, String> hash22 = new Hashtable<Character, String>();
    hash22.put('e', "age-52");
    hash22.put('f', "height-6");
    hash22.put('d', "2");
    vector2.add(hash22);

    Vector<Hashtable<Character, String>> vector3 = new Vector<Hashtable<Character, String>>();
    Hashtable<Character, String> hash31 = new Hashtable<Character, String>();
    hash31.put('g', "pet-dog");
    hash31.put('d', "1");
    vector3.add(hash31);

    Hashtable<Character, String> hash32 = new Hashtable<Character, String>();
    hash32.put('g', "pet-cat");
    hash32.put('d', "2");
    vector3.add(hash32);

    // Your final vector
    Vector<Hashtable<Character, String>> mergedVector = new Vector<Hashtable<Character, String>>();

    // Considering every vector has the same size
    for (int i = 0; i < vector1.size(); i++) {
        mergedVector.add(vector1.get(i));
        mergedVector.add(vector2.get(i));
        mergedVector.add(vector3.get(i));
    }

    // Print the result
    for (Hashtable<Character, String> hash : mergedVector) {
        for (Entry<Character, String> set : hash.entrySet())
            System.out.println("KEY: " + set.getKey() + ", VALUE: " + set.getValue());

        System.out.println("\nNext hashtable.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and Sorry I think I forget to mention that vectors(vector1, vector2, vector3) are not of the same size.I had given an ideal situation here. I want to merge 2 vector based on value of "d".In which ever bracket of 3 vector value of d=1 I want to merge them all in one. And I am getting this vector from database so I cannot put it into hastable statically.

Comment: I think the static puts were just to do the setup. Because we do not have the database to get the data we have to setup the data like you would get it in your program.

Comment: The static values are just to make the example works, like @ManuelM. said. I will make the changes to merge the vector looking at the `d` value and without consider they have the same size, but after the break ;)

Comment: @maqjav: actually i took your code and improved it so it results in the merged vector4 charmi gave as example in his question.